# iOS17 widget button intent refresh UI when request callback

Tags: ios, swiftui, widget, ios17

iOS17 for Interactive Widgets， when I click the widget button， then set the button to loading status, and reset the button status to normal after 1s later.

```
    func perform() async throws -> some IntentResult {

        if let index = TaskDataModel.shared.task.firstIndex(where: {

            $0.id == sceneId

        }) {

            print(" toggle run")

            TaskDataModel.shared.task[index].isCompleted.toggle()

            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {

                TaskDataModel.shared.task[index].isCompleted.toggle()

//                WidgetCenter.shared.reloadTimelines(ofKind: "WidgetExtension")

                WidgetCenter.shared.reloadAllTimelines()

            }

        }

        return .result()

    }
```

the code is woking fine when debugging, however it failed to work when running in real enviroment.
Is there something wrong with my code? And how could I fix the bug ,and implement this function?